# What is the difference between the LIBOR data from the FRB and WSJ?

Tags: interest-rate, adjustable-rate-mortgage

What is the difference between the LIBOR data on the US Federal Reserve Bank's website [https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USD6MTD156N] and the data published in the print edition of the Wall Street Journal?  Many mortgages use the LIBOR "as published in The Wall Street Journal" as an index for ARMs.  But I compared some old data I had from the WSJ (via the Mortgage-X website) with data from the FRB and it's different.  For example the 6 month LIBOR for USD on Mar. 8, 2013 was .449 according to the WSJ/Mortgage-X but the FRB has 0.4474 for the same date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a definitive source for this, but this looks like the Wall Street Journal quote is that of the previous day. This makes sense in the context of the processes of setting LIBOR, and publishing the Wall Street Journal.

If you look at, say, the October 27th, 2015 six-month LIBOR rate in the FRED data, it is 0.53465. If you look at the following day in the X-Mortgage data set, October 28th, 2015, the six month rate is 0.534xx. Ok, let's move forward a day for each data set: the rate for October 28th in FRED is 0.53365 and for October 29th in X-Mortgage is 0.533xx. In fact, lets look at the whole month:

`FRED Date  LIBOR       X-Mortgage  LIBOR
10/1/2015   0.53100     10/2/2015   0.531xx
10/2/2015   0.53450     10/5/2015   0.534xx
10/5/2015   0.52325     10/6/2015   0.523xx
10/6/2015   0.52500     10/7/2015   0.525xx
10/7/2015   0.52660     10/8/2015   0.526xx
10/8/2015   0.52660     10/9/2015   0.526xx
10/9/2015   0.52825     10/12/2015  0.528xx
10/12/2015  0.52625     10/13/2015  0.526xx
10/13/2015  0.52450     10/14/2015  0.524xx
10/14/2015  0.52015     10/15/2015  0.520xx
10/15/2015  0.51590     10/16/2015  0.515xx
10/16/2015  0.51840     10/19/2015  0.518xx
10/19/2015  0.51790     10/20/2015  0.517xx
10/20/2015  0.52440     10/21/2015  0.524xx
10/21/2015  0.52690     10/22/2015  0.526xx
10/22/2015  0.52840     10/23/2015  0.528xx
10/23/2015  0.52690     10/26/2015  0.526xx
10/26/2015  0.53165     10/27/2015  0.531xx
10/27/2015  0.53465     10/28/2015  0.534xx
10/28/2015  0.53365     10/29/2015  0.533xx
10/29/2015  0.54890     10/30/2015  0.548xx
10/30/2015  0.55165     11/2/2015   0.551xx`

Why might there be such a shift? Well, according to [FRED's data source](https://www.theice.com/publicdocs/IBA_LIBOR_FAQ.pdf), LIBOR is set at 11:00am, London time, 7:00am EST. That's too late for the WSJ to print. So, if, on 10/1/2015, the LIBOR rate is set such that the six month average becomes 0.53100 on 10/1/2015, that is what FRED would show. However, that update wouldn't be able to be reflected in the Wall Street Journal until the following day.